# PowerShell Scripts to run on Azure Web App, is it possible?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have created a Function App which hosts PowerShell scripts and its main purpose is to add new users to Azure AD.

I want to get this onto a Web App with a simple GUI such as; First Name, Sure name, and E-mail address and a submit button.

I want to know what the simplest way to achieve this would be? And if it is possible to do.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an Azure Static WebApp to host your form and then have it call the Azure Function to submit the form.

Azure statis webapp docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/getting-started?tabs=vanilla-javascript

Adding an API here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/add-api?tabs=vanilla-javascript

Granted this is all in javascript but the front end would need to be in html/js anyway.

Other alternatives are something like PowerShell Universal if you wanted everything to be in PowerShell.

https://ironmansoftware.com/powershell-universal

I've heard good things about it but never actually used it myself